# Displaying Page Name Without Path in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I created a dashboard using Google Data Studio and currently have a table of all `Page` data (Data pulled in from Google Analytics). I also added a filter to only include pages that contain `/blog` since I want to narrow down blog pages.

This works well. Questions is, how do I display only the names of the blog article instead of the path? Is there another filter or function I can add to strip out the path?

`/blog/culture/article-title` to display `as article-title`

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy option I didn't see. I used `Page Title` dimension.